# Counter vs Timer in C - PIC MCU

Tags: c, pic, mcu

I’m sure it’s best practice to use a timer for let’s say button debouncing logic.

But I have some simple code that just counts inside the main while loop.

Are there any big disadvantages to doing that?

Comment: You mean debouncing based on busy waiting delay? It’s most likely not deterministic, powersaving-unfriendly, making the program not really extensible… the only advantage I can think of is in a context of a write-only, dead simple code. But then again, how long does it take to read the docs on how to configure a timer. Again, it’s not like world ends when busy waiting is used, but the advantages rarely outweigh potential problems with it.

Comment: Imagine you have 5 buttons, and you want to detect press, long press and double click. How are going to implement it in the main loop?

Comment: Generally the best way is to use periodic interrupt (form the timer) and handle debouncing and another buttons related stuff there. Then you can call event handlers for particular events.